# Is it unhealthy to eat the stalk on tomatoes

Tags: food-safety, food-poisoning

Is it unhealthy to eat the stalk on tomatoes, after you've taken everything green off. I mean the white stuff which you can out of the tomato.

Comment: Is petiole or peduncle the right word for the tomato part which is between the leaves and the core?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you haven't used any pesticides or other chemicals on the plant, they are safe to eat.  For the record, so are many species of grass.

However, it probably doesn't have much in the way of nutritional value, and I know for a fact that it doesn't taste very good (personal experience on wondering if it would make a good tooth pick).

The stem (secondary growth I believe being discussed here) has more[(1)](http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/labs/rost/Tomato/Stems/TLS.html) xylem[(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylem) than other parts of the plant:

[image: Diagram of late stage secondary stem growth in tomatoes]

[(3)](http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/labs/rost/Tomato/Stems/secstem3.html)

Quite simply, there are less rough ways to get non-soluble fiber.  I imagine with a good deal of cooking to denature the structure of the stems might lead to something more palatable.

The biggest health concern would probably be for your teeth as eating tough and rough foods will lead to [much greater wear](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26240350) on your teeth (specifically [abrasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrasion_%28dental%29)).

Do let us know if you come up with some good recipes.

Comment: Lol, maybe a nice soup ;)

Comment: @velop remember if this answers your question, please mark it as answered. It help your reputation and our site to.

Comment: If you could enhance your answer with mine I'll accept yours.

Answer (score -1):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato#Consumption)  which states that tomatoes contain low amounts of tomatine and solanine. But

```
solanine concentrations in foliage and green fruit are generally too small to be dangerous unless large amounts are consumed
```